# Как измерить в консоли скорость соединения с интернетом в ubuntu-server?

Tags: ubuntu

Как измерить в консоли скорость соединения с интернетом в ubuntu-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставить iperf и соединиться с каким-нибудь сервером в Интернете, например с моим:

```
iperf -c speedtest.alloincognito.ru
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное :)

Answer (score 1):

простейшая консольная утилита есть на это дело: iftop

Comment: мне кажется, или в описании сказано, что оно показывает текущую загрузку сетевого интерфейса, а не измеряет скорость соединения с Интернетом?    iftop - displays bandwidth usage information on an network interface

Answer (score 0):

В догонку iptraf bmon

Comment: а что за параметр bmon? посмотрел в своём iptrf'е и такого не нашёл.

Comment: это утилита. извеняюсь запятую не поставил

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не о том, но можно mii-tool попробовать

Comment: это не о том.    mii-tool is a Unix command allowing to modify the Network Interface Controller (NIC) parameters.То, что оно позволяет узнать параметры NIC никак не является способом узнать скорость соединения с Интернетом.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install speedometer

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить текстовый браузер 'links2'и через него зайти на сайт проверки скорости - может и получиться.